# Detection of the Internet connection

Tags: networking, internet

There is a *small icon* in the system tray in Windows which changes immediately (or with a little delay) when I `connect / disconnect from Internet`.

How Windows (and other operating systems, too) detects that I'm *just connecting / disconnecting from Internet?*

To be more specific - in the situation *`when I did nothing`* (probably my Internet provider has some problems) and after some time the connection was restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows checks actively for connection to various Microsoft servers and services. If Windows for some reason is unable to connect to those servers or if the link on the interface goes down, then it will show up as unable to connect.

If DNS is unavailable Windows will also flag the connection as being "limited".

More info here:

http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/